# Error with spread operation in array. TS1005: ',' expected. TypeScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, spread-syntax

I cannot figure out what I missed on line `row.sections[SECTION_ID`. It always show me a typo error ','...

> FAQ: `sections` - is an array with `objects` inside. In this case I'm
>   trying modify the specific object of the sections founded by custom
>   flag SECTION_ID.

P.S.

I also tried to put `row.sections[SECTION_ID]` inside an extra brackets `[]`, but unfortunately it does not help... Any solutions?

```
  rows: state.rows.map(
    row =>
      row.ID === action.rowID
        ? {
            ...row,
            sections: [
              ...row.sections,
              row.sections[SECTION_ID]: { // error is here
                ...row.sections[SECTION_ID],
                data: {
                  ...// some data
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        : row
  )
```

Comment: Is sections meant to be an array or an object? It's written with square brackets, making it an array, but then you're trying to put a key/value pair inside it like an object.

Comment: @NicholasTower hi! `sections ` is an array with objects inside, yes. In this case I try to modify the specific object of the `sections` by custom flag `SECTION_ID` to found it in the array

Comment: ok, then are you trying to push an object to the end of the array, or replace an object at a certain index?

Comment: It's hard to tell what output you're trying to get here. Should the second element in your `sections` array be an object?

Comment: @KirkLarkin hi!. The all elements of the `sections` are the `objects`.

Comment: @NicholasTower In this case I try to modify the specific `object` of the `sections` founded by custom flag `SECTION_ID`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot mutate some `element` inside `array` by `spread` operation in such way. Using this approach you'll jus add a new, mutated `element` to the same `array` each time. So, it you want to make it right, you need to use the `map` iterator instead:

```
rows: state.mymaps.rows.map(
    row =>
      row.ID === action.rowID
        ? {
            ...row,
            sections: row.sections.map(
              (section, index) =>
                index === JOIN_SECTION_ID
                  ? {
                      ...section,
                      data: {
                        ...section.data
                      }
                   } : section
             )
          } : row
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to replace an element at a certain index of the array without mutating the array, you can make a shallow copy of the array, and then set the value at that index. For example:

```
state.rows.map((row) => {
  if (rowID !== action.rowID) {
    return row;
  }
  const sectionCopy = [...row.sections];
  sectionCopy[SECTION_ID] = {
    ...row.sections[SECTION_ID],
    data: {
      // some data
    },
  };
  return {
    ...row,
    sections: sectionCopy,
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I also do the same trick in my question post and it does not work via ternary operators, that is the question why...